# Fetch vector tiles after zoom/pan ends in OpenLayers 6

Tags: openlayers, vector-tiles

I am trying to optimize the vector tile loading from my local server. Is there any way or any tileLoadFunction to fetch the tiles only after zoom/pan ends.

I am currently using the below function to optimize

```
tileLoadFunction: (tile, url) => {
  tile.setLoader(function (extent, _resolution, projection) {
    map.once("moveend", () => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        getTile(url, tile, extent, projection);
      }, 1000);
    });
  });
},
```

The settimeout works fine but it fetches all the zoom/pan tiles. I want only the last zoomed/panned tile.

Comment: I do not think it can be done.  The tile state is set to loading before the loader is called, so the loader must either load the tile or set the state to error otherwise the tile queue will get full.  If you subsequently need a tile there is no way to reload if its state is error.

Comment: This could have been done easily before version 6.  The performance justification for the change https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/main/changelog/upgrade-notes.md#always-load-tiles-while-animating-or-interacting may be valid but it does not take account of unnecessary load on servers or that unneeded tiles loaded using using API keys may be chargeable.  One non-API method which does seem to work is to override the layer renderer's tile manager https://codesandbox.io/s/vector-tile-info-forked-rc0ux7?file=/main.js

Comment: @Mike. Thanks. It worked as expected. Is there any way to add a delay of let's say 2 sec before fetching from the server